# How to pass a php variable value in jquery selector?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-selectors

I want to highlight that portion of a mapped image whose id is retrieved from mysql database.
I have stored the id in $loc variable. Now using jquery selectors I want to pass this php variable in my jquery selector so that it will highlight the portion of image having the same id as in $loc.
Here is my working code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.maphilight.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
        $(".mapping").maphilight();


    $(".hoverable").css("border", "3px solid red");


    var data = $('#cr2').data('maphilight') || {};  
    data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
    $('#cr1').data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight'); // portion to always highlight (I WANT TO PASS THE PHP VARIABLE $LOC INSTEAD OF '#CR1'

});<area shape="poly" id="cr1" class="room" coords="549,272,489,334,534,377,594,316" href="www.msn.com" target="_top" alt="CR1" name="room-1">
```

Comment: I want to pass the value of $loc (php variable) into jquery selector in place of '#cr1'. In the second last line ! Please help

Comment: Why can't you simply change `$('#cr1')` to be `$('#<?php echo $loc; ?>')` ?

Comment: Oh thanks alot it works, I am actually new to jquery , haven't thought that I can pass php code inside script tag ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace **#cr1** with `#<?php echo $loc ?>`

Instead of:

```
$('#cr1').data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
```

Use:

```
$('#<?php echo $loc ?>').data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
```

Comment: You probably also need the `#` in the selector.

Comment: @Matt I am following you on Twitter

Answer (score -1):

You can use `json_encode` function and pass the php variable `$loc` as a parameter

For example

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode($loc); ?>;

jQuery.each(data, function(i,event) {
   // alert(event.toSource());
   var id = event.id;  // here id is the array of the value based on the php variable for $loc
   badge_name = event.name; // here name is the array of the value based on the php variable for $loc
});
```

Comment: I got it working , just by echoing the php variable inside jquery selector. Why go for a long code when it can be done in a short code :) @Matt